# Very strange problem with Wordpress Blog

Tags: wordpress

http://onlinedienstleister24.de/ has 2 designs.

After I changed the design all settings were saved successfully, yet I still get the old style... so I have deleted the old one.

If you click on a link in the menu:

- Dienstleistungen
- Wir über uns
- Impressum & Kontakt

you get the new design and all is ok, but on the first visit you always get the old sytle...

Why????

Update:

If I use http://www.onlinedienstleister24.de/ the site will load correctly.

I don't think the problem is with the browser cache.

Update 2.0

my htaccess

```
# Das Filtermodul aktivieren.
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE

# Einige Browser verstehen kein gzip:
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip

# Andere schon...
BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

# Bilddateien nicht komprimieren
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary

# "Vary: Accept-Encoding"-Header einfuegen (wichtig bei Proxys)
# (ben�tigt das headers-Modul)
Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
#ExpiresActive On
#ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 5184000 seconds"
#ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 5184000 seconds"
#ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 5184000 seconds"
#ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 5184000 seconds"
#ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 5184000 seconds"
#ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 5184000 seconds"
#ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 5184000 seconds"
#ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 5184000 seconds"
</IfModule>

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I can tell you why this is happening, but I don't know how to solve it (because of my limited knowledge of how you're doing URL routing).

If you click on the link: http://onlinedienstleister24.de/wp-content/themes/freshfolio/style.css (the theme style) it actually gets routed to http://www.onlinedienstleister24.de/wp-content/themes/freshfolio/style.css, while the actual URL of the CSS file is http://www.onlinedienstleister24.de/wp-content/themes/novocane/style.css. It might be a problem with a bad `.htaccess` file, but I'm not really sure how you're server is doing the routing.

Comment: @Fincha this could have been set up by your web host, outside the htaccess file. What do you want to have as the address in the end - the www. one or the one without?

Comment: hm... both :) i call now the support

Comment: @Fincha having them both is not a good idea because of duplicate content. Have one redirect to the other

Comment: that was a problem with supercache, i have deleted this plugin but tehre was stil some files on my server :)

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a subdomain issue.

When I enter the site through `onlinedienstleister24.de`, the style is broken.

When I enter it through `www.onlinedienstleister24.de`, it works.

It looks like the domain without www is pointing to a different web root than the `www.` one.

Comment: thats what i mean, no design becouse  that is the old one (i have deleted)... click on some links and you will get the right one...

Comment: both of them goes onto the folder /wordpress/ on my host, but I think that will be the Problem... thanks for advice :)

Answer (score 0):

onlinedienstleister24.de

www.onlinedienstleister24.de

is this multisite installation ?